# Appending to a multidimensional array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I am filtering the arrays `a` and `b` for likewise values and then I want to append them to a new array `difference` howveer I get the error: `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 2`. How would I be able to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
difference= np.array([[]])


for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if np.allclose(i, j, atol=0.5):
            difference = np.concatenate((difference,[i]))
```

Expected Output:

```
[[ 0. 55.],[  0.  123.5]]
```

Comment: Repeated concatenate in a loop is both hard to do right, and inefficient.Here you need to understand array dimensions.  There's no room for guessing or approximating.

Comment: Why aren't you collecting the differences in a list?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate an array where the elements has size 0

```
difference= np.array([[]])  # Specifically [ [<no elements>] ]
```

To an array where the elements has size 2

```
np.concatenate((difference,[i]))  # Specifically [i] which is [ [ 0., 55.] ]
```

Instead of initializing it with an empty array which has the size of 0, you could try just calling [.reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) on the difference.

```
# difference= np.array([[]])  # Old code
difference= np.array([]).reshape(0, 2)  # Updated code
```

Output

```
[[  0.   55. ]
 [  0.  123.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.array([[]])` shape is (1, 0). To make it work, it should be (0, 2):

```
difference= np.zeros((0, *a.shape[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [22]: a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
    ...: b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
```

Using a straight forward list comprehension:

```
In [23]: [i for i in a for j in b if np.allclose(i,j,atol=0.5)]
Out[23]: [array([ 0., 55.]), array([  0. , 123.5])]
```

But as for your concatenate.  Look at the shape of the arrays:

```
In [24]: np.array([[]]).shape
Out[24]: (1, 0)
In [25]: np.array([i]).shape
Out[25]: (1, 1)
```

Those can only be joined on axis 1; default is 0, giving you the error.  Like wrote in the comment, you have to understand arrays shapes to use `concatenate`.

```
In [26]: difference= np.array([[]])
    ...: for i in a:
    ...:     for j in b:
    ...:         if np.allclose(i, j, atol=0.5):
    ...:             difference = np.concatenate((difference,[i]), axis=1)
    ...: 
In [27]: difference
Out[27]: array([[  0. ,  55. ,   0. , 123.5]])
```

### vectorized

A whole-array approach:

broadcase `a` against `b`, producing a (5,5,2) closeness array:

```
In [37]: np.isclose(a[:,None,:],b[None,:,:], atol=0.5)
Out[37]: 
array([[[ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]]])
```

Find where both columns are true, and where at least one "row" is:

```
In [38]: _.all(axis=2)
Out[38]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]])
In [39]: _.any(axis=1)
Out[39]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False])
In [40]: a[_]
Out[40]: 
array([[  0. ,  55. ],
       [  0. , 123.5]])
```