# Formatting multi dimensional arrays in rows Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am filtering the arrays `a` and `b` for likewise values and then I want to append them to a new array `difference`. I am trying to organize it so that each time it concatenates it adds a new row to `differences` just like the Expected Output below, how would I be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
c = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,121]])
d = np.array([[0,40],[1,55],[0,24],[0,123],[0,4]])
e = np.array([[1,40.2],[1,55]])

def comp(a, other):
    try: 
        difference= np.array([[]])
        for i in a:
            for j in other:
                if np.allclose(i, j, atol=0.5):
                    difference = np.concatenate((difference,[i]), axis=1)
        print(difference)
    except:
        print("No difference")

comp(a, b)
comp(a, c)
comp(a, d)
comp(a, e)
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   55.    0.  123.5]]
[[ 0. 12.  1. 40.  0. 55.]]
[[  0.  123.5]]
[[ 1. 40.]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[  0.   55. ], [ 0.  123.5]]
[[ 0. 12.], [ 1. 40.], [ 0. 55.]]
[[  0.  123.5]]
[[ 1. 40.]]
```

Comment: It really just looks like you're missing a line to make the sub-lists in a level of your for-loop. You also shouldn't use `numpy.concatenate` in loops because it makes a new array and copies to it each time. Instead you should make 1 list and `append` sub-lists or sub-arrays to it. If you need to return a NumPy array you can just turn the list into an array `np.array(theOneList)`

Comment: Last time you asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051675/appending-to-a-multidimensional-array-python)  there were at least two answers pointing out the `difference` shape is wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending to a multidimensional array Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051675/appending-to-a-multidimensional-array-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm tempted to mark this as a duplicate, since it doesn't add anything to your previous question - but my answer doesn't have any upvotes.  So here's my list comprehension again:

```
In [92]: def comp(a, b):
    ...:     return [i for i in a for j in b if np.allclose(i,j,atol=0.5)]
    ...: 
In [93]: a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
    ...: b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
    ...: c = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,121]])
    ...: d = np.array([[0,40],[1,55],[0,24],[0,123],[0,4]])
    ...: e = np.array([[1,40.2],[1,55]])
In [94]: comp(a,b)
Out[94]: [array([ 0., 55.]), array([  0. , 123.5])]
In [95]: comp(a,c)
Out[95]: [array([ 0., 55.])]
In [96]: comp(a,d)
Out[96]: [array([  0. , 123.5])]
In [98]: comp(a,e)
Out[98]: [array([ 1., 40.])]
```

and without the unnecessary array wrapper

```
In [99]: comp(a.tolist(), b.tolist())
Out[99]: [[0.0, 55.0], [0.0, 123.5]]
```